# Using For Loop for Inventory Update

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a script to update my inventory based on a parts list on another sheet.  I want it to check each row of one column on one sheet, check to see if it matches any of the cells in another column on another sheet (Like a lookup table would.)  If that statement is true, I want it to subtract the number on my parts list from the number in inventory.

What I have now will check if the part # on the parts list matches the part # of the same row on the inventory list.  That does work.  What won't work is getting it to check the next row for that part number if there isn't a match.

I think an if/else statement should do it, but I don't know how to phrase it.  I've used file iterators to search in folders, and the concept seems similar, but I'm not sure how to make it iterate over rows.

There may also be a simpler/cleaner way to set this up, but I'm fairly new to Google Scripts and I was designing this off of a similar task I've done before.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
var bomtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'BOM!A5:M2004')
var invtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'Inv Temp!A2:Q1658') 
var invpartno = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!A2:A1658');
var invpartqty = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!M2:M1658');

 for(var i = 0; i < bomtactics.values.length; i++){    
     var BOMquantity = bomtactics.values[i][0];
     var BOMpartnum = bomtactics.values[i][1];
     var invpartnum = invtactics.values[i][0];
     var invquantity = invtactics.values[i][12];

     var newqty = invquantity - BOMquantity
     Logger.log("New Quantity: ", newqty)

     //This works if the Bill of Materials list is an exact match in placement with the inventory list
     if(BOMpartnum == invpartnum){
       SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getRange('Inv Temp!M'+(i+2)).setValue(newqty).setFontColor('Red');
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   }
 else
 {
   // How to get it to check multiple records like a lookup table.
 }
```

Link to sample spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1txMmXYMO549qqi5HhXL_bBHiCcXkgbLLCP3ML1xoQ9k/edit#gid=669780412

Comment: Quick clarifying question. When you say, "What won't work is getting it to check the next row for that part number if there isn't a match", do you need it to check every other row in the inventory list if a match isn't found in the same row, or do you need it to just check the *next* row?

Comment: I want it to check every other row until it finds a match.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a little quicker since your not writing the updated quanity for every part number separately.  Instead your saving the changes into an array and writing it all at one time at the end of the script.

```
function noName() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var bomsh=ss.getSheetByName('BOM');
  var bomrg=bomsh.getRange(5,1,bomsh.getLastRow()-4,bomsh.getLastColumn())
  var bomvA=bomrg.getValues();
  var invsh=ss.getSheetByName('Inv Temp');
  var invrg=invsh.getRange(2,1,invsh.getLastRow()-1,invsh.getLastColumn());
  var invvA=invrg.getValues();
  var invAdj=invsh.getRange(2,13,invsh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var invAdjfA=invsh.getRange(2,13,invsh.getLastRow()-1,1).getBackgrounds();
  invAdjfA.forEach(function(r){r[0]='#ffffff'});//resetting the background to white
  for(var i=0;i<bomvA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<invvA.length;j++) {
      //compare part numbers
      if(bomvA[i][1]==invvA[j][0]) {
        //if match is found update quantities
        invAdj[j][0]-=bomvA[i][0];
        invAdjfA[j][0]="#ff0000";
      }
    }
  } 
  //Load all quantity adjustments
  invsh.getRange(2,13,invsh.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(invAdj);
  invsh.getRange(2,13,invsh.getLastRow()-1,1).setBackgrounds(invAdjfA);
}
```

//Load all quantity adjustments
  invsh.getRange(2,13,invsh.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(invAdj);
  invsh.getRange(2,13,invsh.getLastRow()-1,1).setBackgrounds(invAdjfA);
}

If multiple people could be doing this simultaneously then you would probably need to use lock service on it so that quantities don't get messed up.

Calculating Column Height:

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

Comment: I tried this out on a sample sheet that had repeated instances of the same part number. It didn't repeat the process for the second instance. (IE line 5 and again on line 25). I can probably come up with something to automatically condense and total the first sheet, but Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: There's no reason that I can see why it doesn't catch both instances.  I'm not breaking the loop.

Comment: I see the same behavior. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there is a bunch of stuff on the Inv Temp page that's not obvious.  It looks like it stop and line 50 or so but actually I've found stuff at line 1700 and following so I changed my pasting of data to paste values only and I have deleted row beyond values that I care about.  I'll continue debugging to see  if I can get the function to work.

Comment: Since I created a column range for Column 13 (M) , I needed the change the method of calculating the new Quantity and so what was happening before is that we were just seeing the last change instead of all of the changes.  Now I'm just subtracting off the value of BOM  from Column 13 of Inv Temp and then posting them all at one time at the end with setValues().  I also added changing the background colors to red for the changes.

Comment: The functions seem to be working now.  Although, there are still some problems with that extra data on the spreadsheets.  If that's not easily fixed then using getLastRow() may not be the answer.  It might be better to get the last row by calculating the height of column1.  And that's why I added that extra function.

Comment: That worked!  I also took my full inventory list (about 1700 items) and the biggest part list I could find, and it handled it almost instantly, so it should be good as far as I can see the needs growing.  Thanks

Comment: Great. If you any more problems let us know.

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to check every other row until it finds a match.

In that case, instead of an if-else statement, I think a nested for-loop will work better.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
var bomtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'BOM!A5:M2004')
var invtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'Inv Temp!A2:Q1658') 
var invpartno = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!A2:A1658');
var invpartqty = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!M2:M1658');

  for(var i = 0; i < bomtactics.values.length; i++){    
    var BOMquantity = bomtactics.values[i][0];
    var BOMpartnum = bomtactics.values[i][1];

    for (var j = 0; j < invtactics.values.length; j++) {
      var invpartnum = invtactics.values[j][0];
      var invquantity = invtactics.values[j][12];

      if(BOMpartnum == invpartnum) {
        var newqty = invquantity - BOMquantity
        Logger.log("New Quantity: ", newqty)

        SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getRange('Inv Temp!M'+(j+2)).setValue(newqty).setFontColor('Red');
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();

        break;
      }
  }
```

Note the nested loop is stopped with `break;` when a match is found.

Obviously, this approach has the disadvantage of being slower and more inefficient, especially if the match is typically in the same row. If this is a small data set though, the performance may not matter.

Comment: It seemed to work quickly with my full inventory list, which is about 1500 items. and one of the larger parts lists we've had.

I did have a question. I tried this out on a sample sheet that had repeated instances of the same part number.  It didn't repeat the process for the second instance.  

I can probably come up with something to automatically condense and total the first sheet, but Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: @StephenSchonewolf - If you need the check to continue after 1 match is found, simply remove the `break;` line, and the inner loop will continue until it's gone through the entire inventory sheet.

Comment: Removing the Break didn't do it.   I watched it happen from the Inv Temp tab as the script was running.  It subtracted the first instance, and then it subtracted the second instance from the original value.  (So 5-2=3, and then 5-1=4) instead of (5-2=3 and then 3-1 = 2).   I tried to put another spreadsheet flush after the break, and it just caused the script to run in a never-ending loop.

Comment: I see. Let me ask a few follow-up questions: Is there a reason the same part appears multiple times on the inventory sheet? Will the starting quantity always be the same for all instances of the same item? You could update the code so that  `newqty` is first declared *outside* the inner for-loop, then you update `newqty` inside the inner for-loop when the loop comes across a new instance for the part. That said, this is adding logic to adjust the quantity in multiple rows for the same part when it may better to just clean up the inventory list to only have unique parts appear once on the list.

Comment: The duplicate items would show up on the BOM sheet and not the Inv Temp sheet. The reason the same part may show up on the BOM sheet is because I may have many techs adding their parts they use without searching to see if that part has been used before. I can test whether moving newqty around would work on it so that I can learn more.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to search from all the rows in the Inventory Sheet you can use the [createTextFinder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext) in the range you want to look up. This will give you a direct answer without having to iterate over all the rows.

```
function test() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
  var bomtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'BOM!A5:M2004')
  var invtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'Inv Temp!A2:Q1658') 
  var invpartno = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!A2:A1658');
  var invpartqty = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!M2:M1658');

  var lookupRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getRange('Inv Temp!A2:Q1658');

 for(var i = 0; i < bomtactics.values.length; i++){    
   var BOMquantity = bomtactics.values[i][0];
   var BOMpartnum = bomtactics.values[i][1];
   var invpartnum = invtactics.values[i][0];
   var invquantity = invtactics.values[i][12];

   var textFinder = lookupRange.createTextFinder(BOMpartnum);
   var foundRange = textFinder.findNext();


   var newqty = invquantity - BOMquantity
   Logger.log("New Quantity: ", newqty)


   //This works if the Bill of Materials list is an exact match in placement with the inventory list
   if(foundRange != null){
     SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getRange('Inv Temp!M'+(foundRange.getRow())).setValue(newqty).setFontColor('Red');
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   }else{
     // How to get it to check multiple records like a lookup table.

   }
 }
}
```

Also if you wanted to match the whole cell value instead of a partial match you can use [`matchEntireCell`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder.html#matchentirecellmatchentirecell).

If you want more information you can look at the [`TextFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder.html) documentation.

---

Other thing I would like to suggest is that you can actually get the same results without doing the call directle at the API. Meaning that instead of:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
  var bomtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'BOM!A5:M2004')
  var invtactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, 'Inv Temp!A2:Q1658') 
  var invpartno = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!A2:A1658');
  var invpartqty = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss,'Inv Temp!M2:M1658');

  var lookupRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getRange('Inv Temp!A2:Q1658');
```

You could try to get this directly through APPs Script classes, more specifically [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app):

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var bomtactics = ss.getRange('BOM!A5:M2004').getValues();
  var invtactics = ss.getRange(ss, 'Inv Temp!A2:Q1658').getValues() ;
  var invpartno = ss.getRange(ss,'Inv Temp!A2:A1658').getValues();
  var invpartqty = ss.getRange(ss,'Inv Temp!M2:M1658').getValues();

  var lookupRange = ss.getRange('Inv Temp!A2:Q1658');
```